# script to mount a file system

Tags: filesystems, rhel, mount, date

Can anyone please provide me a shell script which automatically mounts a file system (/mnt/resource)? On every Monday morning, the script should first check whether the file system is mounted or not. If it is not mounted, the script should mount it.

Comment: What OS? Where is the filesystem located? (e.g. hostname: my_nfs_server  shared directory:/data_dir mounts to /mnt/resource)

Comment: Generally, if it is already mounted, and you try to re-mount it, you'll just get an error.

Comment: Hi, OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo).

Comment: on every sunday the server is rebooted. some times it is not rebooted. so when the server reboots the file system is unmounted so i want a script that check the file system and mount it if it is not

Comment: file system is /mnt/disk it is an azure container

Comment: yes if it is already mounted. It will show error. so the script should check weather it's mounted or not (df -h | grep -i /mnt/disk) if it sees the file system then it should not run otherwise it should run the command.

Comment: Why not use the automounter and let it do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Would it really matter if you tried to mount a filesystem that was already mounted (i.e. why not just try it every Monday anyway, and discard the error)?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just place the mount in `/etc/fstab`, since you're RHEL 7. There are number of different configurations you can follow which, when your host is rebooted, will make sure your mount comes up with the machine, using `_netdev` and `auto` flags should take care of your use cases.

[fstab](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/)

[fstab man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)

[You'll be using `mount` with a newly edited `/etc/fstab`.](https://tecadmin.net/mount-and-unmount-filesystem-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/fstab` is intended for this very purpose. A script is not required.
Prerequisites for the server:
the /etc/hosts file must contain the IP FQDN & (short) hostname of your local server, and the remote server.
Your local server should be the first line after the loopback(s):
`127.0.0.1  [IPv4 loopback stuff]
::1        [IPv6 loopback stuff]
10.10.50.10  local_server.mydomain.name  local_server
10.10.10.2   remote_server.mydomain.name remote_server`

The `/etc/fstab` file documents the file systems to mount. Don't mess with these entries. Just add a new line at the end of the file.
`remote_server:/mnt/disk   /mnt/resource   [fstype]  defaults  0 0`
You will need to know the files system type of the azure container file system. Look in the `fstab` man page to determine possible types.
YMMV on the `defaults` field. Use it until you know what to put in there.